# Freecell puzzle unsolvable?

Tags: puzzles, free-cell

I think this freecell puzzle (739671 on Odesys) has no solution but not 100% sure.
Using [this solver](http://fc-solve.shlomifish.org/js-fc-solve/text/) could not solve it. Is there a better solver, or does this really have no solution?

This is the starting layout:

```
8C JD TS 6S 9S 2C 7H
8H 4D TC 8D 9H AS JS
QC AH 9D 5S 5D 3D 2H
QS 8S 6H JH 3C AD KS
4C 6C 7S 6D KC JC
4H 4S 2S KD TD KH
TH 7C 3S 2D AC 7D
QD 3H QH 9C 5H 5C
```

Comment: I just tried it on that website with the default solving method and it solved the puzzle.

Comment: It solved for me also using all the available solution methods.

Comment: Ouch! Right, no idea how THAT puzzle got in there. Wrong one. See edit for the right puzzle.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the wrong puzzle entirely? The revision history records all earlier versions of the post already.

Comment: @Nij I took an edit :) you could have done the same though...

Comment: That is the top result I get when searching for freecell solvers on google and appears several times in the results so guessing you are not going to find anything better.

Comment: And how would that help a new user to practice doing things properly? @DarkCygnus

Comment: @Nij there is some method to the madness: I didn't want the comments by Mosquite and Joe W to appear erroneous (unless one looked at the edit history). Anyway, that one seems unsolvable. Anybody knows of proofs of unsolvability except for evidently unsolvable freecell puzzles.

Comment: @Nij learning by example :)

Comment: That's what the revision history and "no longer needed" flags are for. Once improvements are made, the comments should be removed and a flag by the question asker helps make that happen. @GilbertWeinstein

Comment: Related, possible duplicate (I'd say it's a duplicate except that the answer doesn't address specific games past the original 32000: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/15287/is-there-any-configuration-of-free-cell-that-cannot-be-solved