# Freecell seed that solve itself

Tags: free-cell

As a follow-up to this question: [Is there any configuration of Free Cell that cannot be solved?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/15287/is-there-any-configuration-of-free-cell-that-cannot-be-solved), is there a FreeCell seed that solves itself? (with the auto card-stack built-in in the game)
I know this is possible because the configuration below permits such a thing:

```
K-K-K-K Q-Q-Q-Q  
J-J-J-J T-T-T-T  
9-9-9-9 8-8-8-8  
7-7-7-7 6-6-6-6  
5-5-5-5 4-4-4-4  
3-3-3-3 2-2-2-2  
A-A-A-A
```

Comment: For which version of Free Cell? The original version has only 2^15 different games. The chance that a self solving one is in that small range is rather unlikely.